# RegEx pattern to exclude filename with certain character string

Tags: regex, ant

I'm trying to write a regular expression for an Ant task that excludes files in a directory that end with a certain character sequence.  For example, I have the following three files:

```
file01.js
file02.js
file02-copy.js
```

I want an expression that finds the first two files and ignores the one with "-copy" on the end.  I've tried using `<include>`'s and `<excludes>`'s like so:

```
<fileset dir="." includes="js/">
    <include name="*.js"/>
    <exclude name="*copy*"/>
</fileset>
```

but obviously because its a JS file, its still included.  So I'm trying to use a regular expression to match the files (if anyone has another suggestion please do suggest):

```
<fileset dir="." includes="js/">
    <containsregexp expression="...">
</fileset>
```

And here lies my problem.  I can't find a regEx that does this match for me.  I've tried a few things like `(\w*)(!-copy).js` but this does nothing.  If anyone could help me out I'd be very grateful.

Did I mention that I hate trying to write regEx's?

Comment: Just so we're not solving the wrong problem, could you outline the file/directory structure for your files? Are your file*.js files in the "." directory or in the "js/" directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd skip the include directives, and only add exclude directives for everything that's explicitly excluded. Other files will then be implicitly included.

I don't know what your file structure looks like, so I might be wrong about this one, but maybe this would do the trick:

```
<fileset dir="js" excludes="*copy*" />
```

Comment: This works perfectly, and yeah that is the correct directory structure.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try match for (?m)^(?=.*js)((?!copy.js).)*$

More info can be found in below link. Excellent post.

[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)